# Unable to take continuous data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, stm32

I am taking data(voltage and current) from BMS hardware successfully in STM32CubeIDE but when i transmitting data in MATLAB serially getting limited data like 35 or 100. I checked value on dock-light/ hyper-terminal,it shows correct continuous data.

My code in MATLAB is:

```
clc
clear all
close all
delete(instrfind)
s=serial('COM4','BaudRate',9600,'Terminator','CR');  
fopen(s);
while 1
binary_data = fread(s, 5); 
str = char(binary_data');  
data = str2num(str);
plot(data);
end
```

Comment: For debugging, split `data=str2num(fscanf(s))` into: `str = fscanf(s);` and `data=str2num(str);`, what is the value of `str`?

Comment: @Rotem thanks for your response sir,i already used this as you said above but both gives the same data like 67 data or 120 data means not more than 150.But i want it continuously and should be off when i stop the program. Value of str is:    '2975 2975 2975 2975 .........29' ,here getting 67 char data.

Comment: @Rotem also getting warning like Warning: Unsuccessful read: A timeout occurred before the Terminator was reached.
'serial' unable to read all requested data. For more information on possible reasons, see Serial Read Warnings.

Comment: It seems that you forgot to put `\n` at the end of each new value you transmit in the STM32. In the STM32, you should use something like `sprintf(str, '%d\n');`, transmit `str`

Comment: The default terminator when you create serial is 'LF' (line feed character). The ASCII value of the character is 10). The `fscanf` MATLAB function looks for the terminator character (to know when one string transmission ends).

Comment: @Rotem thanks for your response sir,i solved this problem but another problem is that i am getting contineous value on matlab but it is NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ....., why this happen sir?

Comment: It looks like the STM32 transmits "NaN" strings. In the STM32, are you using something like `sprintf(str, '%d\n', (int)x);` or `sprintf(str, '%f\n', (double)x);`?

Comment: @Rotem ,sir STM32 transmitting correct data ,i checked it on docklight.I think problem is in matlab code.I am able to take finite data in matlab but don't know how to take continuously .Sir ,what will happen if i use while loop in matlab for continuous data?

Comment: Each call to `str = fscanf(s)` reads characters from the serial port until receiving 'LF' (`\n`) character (the default timeout is 10 seconds). Did you verify that you are transmitting `\n` at the end of each new transmitted string?

Comment: I am using the command :          HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, a, 5, 1000); in while loop where 'a ' is char a[5],so how can i use here '\n'?

Comment: It looks like `HAL_UART_Transmit` is designed for transmitting binary data (not text). I never used it...

Comment: How do you fill the value of array `a` with the number (fill the digits as text)?

Comment: You can try the following code: `char a[10];int n = 12345;sprintf(a, "%d\n", n);int len = strlen(a);HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, a, len, 1000);`

Comment: When transmitting text data, you can't transmit same number of characters each time. You need to transmit the number of characters equals to the length of the string, and the string must be terminated with `\n`. (You do have an option to transmit and receive binary data instead of text).

Comment: You had a answer which satisfied your original question. Please do not change the original question to ask for more. Post a completely new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an ad-hoc solution, you can use [fread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.fread.html) instead of `fscanf`:

Assuming you are keeping `HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, a, 5, 1000);` in the STM32.
You are transmitting `5` bytes in each transmission.
You can read the `5` bytes into character array (in MATLAB) using `fread`, and convert the character array to number.

```
binary_data = fread(s, 5); %Read 5 bytes from serial port (5 uchar elements) to array binary_data.
str = char(binary_data'); %Convert uchar array to character array. 
data = str2num(str) %Convert character array to number
```

When reading binary data, the number of bytes to read must be known from advance (5 bytes in your case).
there is no need for `\n` termination.

---

Example for continuous graph plotting:

Execute the following code as "stand alone" to see how it supposes to work.

Replace the code lines according to comments.

```
X = 1:100;
Y = zeros(1, 100); %Initialize array for storing 100 samples
figure;
h = plot(X, Y, 'o-'); %Plot the initial graph before loop begins.  

%Endless loop, until user closes the graph figure.
while (isvalid(h))
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %Replace the following line:
    data = rand();

    %With:
    %binary_data = fread(s, 5); %Read 5 bytes from serial port (5 uchar elements) to array binary_data.
    %str = char(binary_data'); %Convert uchar array to character array. 
    %data = str2num(str) %Convert character array to number
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %Move elements 2:100 one to the "left side", and add new sample at the end (at the "right side").
    Y(1:99) = Y(2:100);
    Y(100) = data;

    h.YData = Y; %Update plot data.
    drawnow; %Refresh plot drawing

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %Remove the following line:
    pause(0.1);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
end
```

Remark:
There is a chance that plotting (graphics) is not fast enough.
In that case yow need to plot every 10 samples (or every 100 samples) depends of the rate the STM32 transmits the data samples.

Comment: thank you so much sir,now i am getting continuous data in matlab,thanks once again but facing another problem is that i am  getting blank graph,want it contineous like data.

Comment: I added an example for continuous graph plotting to my answer.

Comment: as per your above suggestion,only y axis is varying but according to that time axis is not changing.So its not contineous data?

Comment: The X axis marks the position of a sample out of the last 100 samples. You can change X to something else. Like `X = X + 1;h.XData = X;`

Comment: thank you so much sir,its working continuously.Now another problem is with GUI.When i run GUI,it shows matlab graph,not showing graph in GUI.Why this happen sir?

Comment: Remove the `figure` command, and try. If the graph is drawn in a wrong place, you need to set the first parameter of `plot` command to the correct handle of the axes in you GUI. I can't give a good answer, without knowing the internal structure of your GUI.

Comment: sir,as you said remove figure command and run,i already done this but not getting graph in GUI. I edited GUI code above,please check it once and correct me.

Comment: Try: `plot(handles.axes1, X, Y, 'o-');`

Comment: getting blank graph sir.Sir i want to tell you one thing that i am getting continuous data in matlab with respect to samples not with respect to time.Getting blank graph in GUI, is because of that sir?i tried to vary data with respect to time but not getting,so by default ploting with respect to samples.

Comment: As I told you, I can't answer an exact solution because  I don't know the internal structure of your GUI.

Comment: ok sir ,you already taken too much effort for me,thank you so much sir.